# Binding changes between wpf 3.5 and 4

Tags: wpf, binding, propertychanged

Regarding the following code.

```
    public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public int Model { get; private set; }
        public ViewModel(int _model)
        {
            Model = _model;
        }

        PropertyChangedEventHandler m_propertyChangedEventHandler;
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged
        {
            add
            {
                m_propertyChangedEventHandler += value;
                Console.WriteLine("Add");
            }
            remove
            {
                m_propertyChangedEventHandler -= value;
                Console.WriteLine("Remove");
            }
        }
    }

    public partial class Window1 : Window
    {
        public ObservableCollection<ViewModel> ViewModels { get; private set; }

        public Window1()
        {
            ViewModels = new ObservableCollection<ViewModel>() { new ViewModel(1), new ViewModel(2), new ViewModel(3) };
            DataContext = this;
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        protected override void OnPreviewMouseDoubleClick(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnPreviewMouseDoubleClick(e);
            Content = new Button();
        }
    }


<Window x:Class="WpfApplication97.Window1"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding ViewModels}"
             DisplayMemberPath="Model"/>
</Window>
```

On double clicking, the windows content will be replaced, which should cleanup the existing controls bindings (unregistering with PropertyChanged, and entering the remove accessor).

Running under .net 4.0 it works as expected, but not under 3.5 (in which case the Remove doesn't get called until you close the window)

Why is this, and can I get the same behavior in 3.5?

Comment: working for me both in .net 4.0 and .net 3.5

Comment: Really? I just tried again with a new project (using vs2010), with the default .net 4 as the Target Framework, and its fines, but as soon as I set the target framework to 3.5, the remove handler stops getting called